# Flushing stdin after inputing a string, to subsequently input next char

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, flush

I want to input a string, the subsequently a char for further use in my program, but whenever I try to input a string longer than 10 characters, all that's leftover, goes into my next input request. I tried using scanf("%*c"), but it couldn't flush all my input.

```
char tab[11];
char c;
printf("Give me a string: ");
scanf("%10[^\n]%*c", tab);
printf("%s\n", tab);
printf("Give ma a char: ");
scanf("%c", &c);
```

How should I properly deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `getchar` in a loop until you read a newline:

```
printf("Give me a string: ");
scanf("%10[^\n]", tab);

while (getchar() != '\n');

printf("%s\n", tab);
printf("Give me a char: ");
scanf("%c", &c);
```

Comment: Oh yes, if I input something, I always end up with '\n' at the end, that solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Can it be accomplished without using getchar()?

Comment: @RPAnimation `getchar` is the preferred way to do this.